# How to set up extended tool tips in WPF Ribbon Control?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I have been playing with the new [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877) and looking at the tutorials published in the WPF Team Blog. The [tutorial for extended tool tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpf/how-can-i-add-rich-tooltips-to-my-ribbon-controls) shows this screen shot:

[Extended tool tip screen shot http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/800x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-38-64/0871.Post6-_2D00_-Rich-RibbonToolTips.png](http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/800x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-38-64/0871.Post6-_2D00_-Rich-RibbonToolTips.png)

Unfortunately, the tutorial doesn't show the markup to create that tool tip.

I've got a couple of questions about the screen shot that I am hoping someone can help me with:

- How do I embed a paragraph break in the tool tip, like they did in the screen shot?
- How do I assign a Control-key shortcut to a RibbonButton?

As to the second question, I can see how they embedded the '(Ctrl+Shift+C)' in the tool tip--I'm guessing thay just made it part of the ToolTipTitle. What I am trying to figure out is how to assign the Ctrl-key combo to trigger the button press.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answers--actually turned out to be pretty simple.

First question: How to embed newlines? Simply embed a `&#x000A`; character where the newline should appear:

```
ToolTipDescription="Makes the Note List View active.&#x000A;&#x000A;Use the Note List View to browse Notes and to search for them by Tags."
```

Second question: How to assign a Control-key combination? In WPF, we don't assign a control-key to a control. Instead, we create an `<InputBindings>` tag and add our control keys to that tag. We assign each control-key to the same ICommand as the control that it is assigned to. For example, here is a set of input bindings for three different buttons in a Ribbon control:

```
<!-- Control-key shortcuts -->
<ribbon:RibbonWindow.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding NewNote}" Key="A" Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DeleteNote}" Key="D" Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SetNoteTags}" Key="T" Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
</ribbon:RibbonWindow.InputBindings>
```

These input bindings aren't defined in the Ribbon control. Instead, they are defined at the window level--I put mine just after the `<Window.Resources>` tag. To the user, they appears the same as if they had been assigned to the Ribbon control.